# Google crawling, AJAX and HTML5

Tags: ajax, html, web-crawler, hashtag, pushstate

HTML5 allows us to update the current URL without refreshing the browser. I've created a small framework on top of HTML5 which allows me to leverage this transparently, so I can do all requests using AJAX while still having bookmarkable URLs without hashtags. So e.g. my navigation looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on the News link, my framework in fact issues an AJAX GET request (jQuery) for the page and replaces the current content with the retrieved content. After that, the current URL is updated using HTML5's pushState(). However, it is still equally possible to just type http://www.example.com/news in the browser, in which case the content will be provided synchronously of course.

The question now is, will Google crawl the pages for this site? I know that Google provides a [guide](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) for crawling Ajax applications, but the article supposes that hashtags are used for bookmarkability, and I don't (want to) use hashtags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have actual hard links to the pages and they load the same content, Google will crawl your site just fine.

Comment: The question is really how Google does the crawling. Will it just identify all links contained inside the page and then do separate synchronous requests to them, or will it try to "click" on each link, which will maybe not produce the same result as the spider cannot execute any Javascript (or can it?).

Comment: Your links are actual, normal links, so they'll be followed exactly as written. Javascript is never executed by Google.