# confused - html5 history api and google crawler?

Tags: javascript, html, history.js, html5-history

per [Google crawling, AJAX and HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611585/google-crawling-ajax-and-html5)  , google can crawl dynamic pages that use history api, yet it says that google won't execute any javascript on the page. To me that means that an ajax request and dom building wont be made, so google won't be able to index the contents of the page that is loaded in. can anyone please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the answer, you'll need to **provide hard links** for bots.

Just treat it like a user without JavaScript. You should support users with no JavaScript. Feel free to implement the `<noscript>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

So linked on the page is a [guide by google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=nl) on how to make your ajax site crawl able by google. Following the mentioned schema you can do it.

```
www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value
```

This way you can tell google crawlers that your site is ajax crawlable and they will do the rest.